# Placing Wordpress plugin name at the top of the amdin header

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin which I've named 'Solve Maths'. I want this plugin name to be displayed only at the Admin header of the Arthur alone for easy access.

I used the admin_head action hook but once I installed the plugin, the system tells me my plugin has generated these number of characters at the header.

```
<?php function Solve_Maths{ echo  "<a href='Solve_Maths.php'>Solve Maths</a>";} add_action('admin_head','Solve_Maths');?>
```

The Solve_Maths.php is the name of the main plugin file with the header information. I want this file name in the  tag to be shown at the admin header of the user and should execute the file when the link is linked. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to do it. Please check the WordPress Codex and refer to the function add_node: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_node

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'toolbar_link_to_mypage', 999 );

```
function toolbar_link_to_mypage( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $args = array(
        'id'    => 'my_page',
        'title' => 'My Page',
        'href'  => 'http://example.com/my-page/',
        'meta'  => array( 'class' => 'my-toolbar-page' )
    );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args );
}
```

Comment: You genius gurl! Thanks a million!